# How to return a value from a constant array in a single line in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was having a discussion about the fastest execution time possible in C++ for a particular problem.  The question is to create a function that receives a single integer between 1 and 100 inclusive, and returns the square of that number as fast as possible.  Input validation will occur before the function is called, the only thing that matters is execution time.

I came up with a 2-line function that seems pretty quick, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int fastSquare(int i) {

    int returnValue[101] = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 
        169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 
        625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 
        1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 
        2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 
        3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 
        4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 
        5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 
        7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 
        9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000
        };
    return returnValue[i];
}

int main()
{
  int value = 36;
  std::cout << "The square of " << value << " is " << fastSquare(value) << ".\n";
}
```

However, I would like to do it as a single line with no variable declaration.  What would the appropriate syntax be?  This was my latest attempt, that would not compile:

```
#include <iostream>

int fastSquare(int i) {

    return int[] {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 
        169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 
        625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 
        1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 
        2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 
        3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 
        4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 
        5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 
        7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 
        9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000
        }[i];
}

int main()
{
  int value = 36;
  std::cout << "The square of " << value << " is " << fastSquare(value) << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: Note: the number of code lines used has little to no impact on performance after the code has passed through your compilers optimizer. In fact; code written on multiple lines can often be *easier* for the optimizer to understand and thus will result in more optimized code that will run faster. Don't judge code based on line count alone.

Comment: Did you really measure that this was faster than `return i * i`? You basically needs a multiplication to do pointer arithmetic to access `returnValue[i]`... And you need to fetch from memory.

Comment: @Holt Faster than `i * i` *with* compiler optimizations *enabled*... In my experience, most newbies test their code *without* enabling the optimizer, which often leads them to wrong conclusions..

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use a `std::array` in place of a raw array.  Using C++17 the function would become

```
int fastSquare(int i) 
{
    return std::array{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 
        169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 
        625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 
        1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 
        2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 
        3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 
        4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 
        5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 
        7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 
        9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000
        }[i];
}
```

If you can't use C++17 but can use C++11 or C++14 then you can still use `std::array`, you just need to supply the type and size like

```
int fastSquare(int i) 
{
    return std::array<int, 101>{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 
        169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 
        625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 
        1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 
        2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 
        3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 
        4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 
        5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 
        7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 
        9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000
        }[i];
}
```

---

If you don't want to use a `std::array` then in order to use a raw array you need to introduce a=n alias.  Using `using int_arr = int[101];` in

```
int fastSquare(int i) 
{
    using int_arr = int[101];
    return int_arr{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 
        169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 
        625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 
        1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 
        2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 
        3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 
        4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 
        5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 
        7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 
        9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000
        }[i];
}
```

Allows you to create an temporary array object that you can then access.

---

Do note that doing this can really hurt performance.  They compiler can't/may not be able to optimize out the array building which could outweigh the code of having a table in the first place.  Using

```
constexpr int fastSquare(int i) 
{
    constexpr std::array arr{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 
        169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361, 400, 441, 484, 529, 576, 
        625, 676, 729, 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, 1089, 1156, 1225, 
        1296, 1369, 1444, 1521, 1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 
        2116, 2209, 2304, 2401, 2500, 2601, 2704, 2809, 2916, 3025, 
        3136, 3249, 3364, 3481, 3600, 3721, 3844, 3969, 4096, 4225, 
        4356, 4489, 4624, 4761, 4900, 5041, 5184, 5329, 5476, 5625, 
        5776, 5929, 6084, 6241, 6400, 6561, 6724, 6889, 7056, 7225, 
        7396, 7569, 7744, 7921, 8100, 8281, 8464, 8649, 8836, 9025, 
        9216, 9409, 9604, 9801, 10000
        };
    return arr[i];
}
```

saves you that creation cost and also lets you use this at compile time.

Comment: I know that's what OP asked, but you could point out that this way, compiler does not (cannot?) optimize out the `std::array` creation at each call, a `static constexpr` array would be much better.

Comment: @Holt I've added to the answer

Comment: I don’t know if the `constexpr` changes things, but function-local static’s get initialized they first time the function is called. So the latest version is fast the second time it’s called, but not the first time.

Comment: @PeteBecker I would assume that the array is constant initialized so there shouldn't be a run time hit.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica — that’s certainly possible, but it’s not required.

Answer (score 2):

Each of the approaches suggested in the answer initializes an array each time the function is called. Get rid of that:

```
static const int squares[] = {
    0, 1, 4, /* et cetera */, 10000
};

int fast_square(int i) { return squares[i]; }
```

Note that this also fixes the off-by-one error in all the proposed solutions.